# Azure DevOps as CI/CD tool for Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, ant, ci, azure, ant-script

Has someone tried using Azure DevOps as CI/CD tool for a Salesforce project?

If so, what are the cons? Am I able to use sfdx or at least ant scripts for testing and deploying?

If Azure is not an option, could you suggest free alternatives for private repos, which can be used with Salesforce projects?

Comment: GitLab Pipelines works fine and is free for private repos. I've never used Azure DevOps. You can successfully run SFDX and Ant on pretty much any container-based CI solution.

Comment: I used it and it works fine. It's more a question of which tool you want to use for your CI, but in regards to the SFDX tooling it will work the same way with Azure DevOps, GitLab Pipelines or whatever other CI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We have 3 CI/CDs going to SF. Each first has a Build box that runs unit test, and then a manual Azure task deploys to a Test box with no unit tests run. Then, we have a few Azure tasks that execute other types of tests.

We deploy with Ant scripts, and test with Selenium and backend tests via REST.

Comment: cc @Fabien, I have set up azure-pipelines.yml so that it deploys successfully.  However, all metadata in the repo on that branch is deployed every time.  Is there a way to deploy only specific metadata, like an Apex Class that I just changed?  I tried changing the contents of src/package.xml but it makes no difference to what is deployed.  (Interestingly, changing the API version specified in src/package.xml does have an effect.)  So, can I determine which metadata is deployed?